# ssh rviz: cannot connect to X server

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I am using indigo in ubuntu14.04.2. I am trying to connect my desktop computer(zyq.local) and another computer(thinker.local). I can ping them from each one, and I have set the hostname and host_master_uri like this:
in my desktop computer:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=zyq.local
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://thinker.local:11311
```

in another:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=thinker.local
```

then I login the robot computer through ssh

```
ssh thinker.local -l think
roscore &
roslaunch rbx1_bringup fake_pi_robot.launch
```

after this I open another terminal in my desktop computer an connect robot computer again

```
ssh thinker.local -l think
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find rbx1_nav`/sim.rviz
```

now error occurs:`rviz: cannot connect to X server` 
I do not why, two computers can ping each other. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236799/ssh-rviz:-cannot-connect-to-x-server/) by [yongqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27003/yongqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default a ssh connection does not allow any graphical interface to be displayed.  To allow this you have to add the -X argument to the connection.

It should be something like

```
ssh -X thinker.local -l think
```

Then you will be able to open any GUI.

Regards,

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yongqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27003/yongqi/) on 2016-06-13**:
thanks, it works.I have another question.When I control the robot through desktop computer without ssh like this`zyq@zyq:~$ rosrun rviz rviz -d` rospack find rbx1_nav`/sim.rviz`, it told me `[rospack] Error: package 'rbx1_nav' not found`. But I have set the HOSTNAME and URI, what should I do thanks

**Comment by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on 2016-06-13**:
This is because probably you don't have the `rbx1_nav` package on your desktop computer. Maybe just run rviz `rosrun rviz rviz` and then add the displays manually

**Comment by [yongqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27003/yongqi/) on 2016-06-13**:
no, I don't have this package. But I have it in my robot computer, I want to add the displays manually on my desktop computer while don't use ssh. Can this be achieved? If not, I don't know what is the HOST_MASTER_URI used for(I have set it http://thinker.local:11311). Thanks very much.

**Comment by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on 2016-06-14**:
Yes, you can manually add the displays in your desktop computer. The ROS_MASTER_URI variable is used to tell ROS that the roscore is running on your robot computer, and therefore being able to read the topics on that computer.

**Comment by [yongqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27003/yongqi/) on 2016-06-14**:
Thanks a lot

**Comment by [Dhuzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/77081/dhuzi/) on 2023-03-29**:
hello，I have got the same issue, and after I used the command 'ssh -X .....', the issue was still here. What could be the issue ? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You forgot to enable X11 Forwarding. Try to use

```
ssh -X thinker.local -l think
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find rbx1_nav`/sim.rviz
```

Note: -X (upper case) enables X11 Forwarding whereas -x (lower case) disables it.

---

Originally posted by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) with karma: 305 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2